# how get reponse body html with curl

Tags: php, html, curl

I use a curl script to send information from a form. This form redirects to another page to validate the information. I would like to retrieve the body of the page where the processing must be validated

Currently, i see the page display, but just idk how get this html...

my curl :

```
$url = "https://www.website.com/porte_transferer.php";


//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $valueRessource);
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

with that i see the page, but idk what add for take this html

Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

you can use  htmlentities($result); to get the row returned html ,
and , for printing it echo htmlentities($result);

Comment: $result = curl_exec($ch);

echo htmlentities($result);

that return 1

Answer (score 0):

you should follow redirects... I bet a fiver that the site sends you a 30x status and some location to follow

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: that dont work :/